# Code execute even if where condition is false

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have problem with `if let where`, the code inside the braces execute even if the where condition is false

```
   if let child = value["child"]  where child[0]["src"] != nil {
     print("Thank you :3")
     continue
   }
```

the `child[0]["src"]` is nil

**Edit** 
 
I solved the problem by add another let , but still don't get why the code above not work.

```
   if let child = value["child"] ,let src = child[0]["src"] where src != nil {
      let imglink = src as! String;
      self.content.append(NSURL(string: imglink)!);
      continue
   }
```

Comment: my answer was that :)

Comment: Instead of answering in the question, add your answer as.. an answer! It's encouraged to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `where` element, you can make multiple check like the below

```
if let child = value["child"] , source = child[0]["src"] {
     print("Thank you :3")
     print("\(child) - \(source)")
     continue
   }
```